# excessive space between edition and location, bib entry of type inbook

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, bibtex

My issue is with the space that appears between the edition and the location. I am using the IEEE citation sytle guide. I have been trying to remove the space that appears but to no avail. Any help would be great.

e.g.

```
@inbook{Shulin-ECC-General-04 ,
Key = {Shulin-ECC-General-04},
Author = {S.~Lin and D.~J.~Costello},
Title = {Error Control Coding},
Publisher ={Prentice Hall},
Address = {Upper Saddle River, NJ},
edition = {2nd},    
Year = {2004}
}
```

The output looks like:

> [45] S. Lin and D. J. Costello, in Error Control Coding, 2nd ed.¨extra spaces appear here¨ Upper Saddle River,NJ: Prentice Hall, 2004.

There are additional 3 white spaces which appear between the edition and location. How can I remove it?

MWS:

```
\documentclass[chap]{thesis}



% Use the first command below if you want captions over 1 line indented. A side
% effect of this is to remove the use of bold for captions (thesis default).
% To restore bold, also include the second line below.
\usepackage[hang]{caption2}      % to indent subsequent lines of captions
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\bfseries} % bold caption (needed with caption 
                  %package to restore boldface.)
%\includeonly{rpichap1}  % use \includeonly to process only
            % the file(s) listed inside the braces                       

\usepackage{textcomp, threeparttable, booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,cite,graphicx,times,paralist}
\usepackage{color, multirow,epsfig,graphicx,url,mdwtab,amssymb,eqparbox,stfloats,color,multirow,array,footnote}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{color, multirow, array, footnote}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Acronyms%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[acronym,toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Acronyms%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareListParser{\wordlist}{ }%

\DeclareRobustCommand{\capitalise}[1]{%
  \def\addspace{}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\addspace\makefirstuc{##1}\def\addspace{ }}%
  \wordlist{#1}%
}

%Remove the dot at the end of glossary descriptions
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}

\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
%\usepackage{setspace}
\newtheorem{property}{Property}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
%\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}[section]
\newtheorem{observation}{Observation}[section]
%\newtheorem{procedure}{Procedure}[section]

\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]
\renewcommand\footnotemark{}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   end titlepage info  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


Nothing~\cite{Shulin-ECC-General-04}.

{\small \baselineskip 12pt \specialhead{REFERENCES}
\begin{singlespace}
%\let\secfnt\undefined
%\newfont{\secfnt}{ptmb8t at 12pt}
%\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\small}{}{}
\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont
\bibliography{reference}
\end{singlespace}
}

\end{document}
```

I have included all the headers in case there is any conflict between packages that I am not aware of.

Also the above reference can be saved as reference.bib to compile the above code.

After some additional investigation.
I find that the generated .bib file at the output is as follows:

```
\bibitem{Shulin-ECC-General-04}
S.~Lin and D.~J. Costello, \emph{Error Control Coding}, 2nd~ed.\hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Upper Saddle River, NJ: Prentice Hall, 2004.
```

So if there is a way to get rid of the ¨\hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax¨ in between all the book references that bibtex generates that would be great.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately the `IEEEtran.bst` style for BibTeX hardwires that

```
\hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax
```

in it, so one has to change the style.

Find `IEEEtran.bst` on your system and copy it in the directory where you have the main file for your thesis, with a name such as `myIEEEtran.bst`. Open the new file with any text editor (the one you use for LaTeX files is fine) and find in it the lines

```
% This is the LaTeX spacer that is used when a larger than normal space
% is called for (such as just before the address:publisher).
FUNCTION {large.space} { "\hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax " }
```

Change them to

```
% This is the LaTeX spacer that is used when a larger than normal space
% is called for (such as just before the address:publisher).
%FUNCTION {large.space} { "\hskip 1em plus 0.5em minus 0.4em\relax " }
%%%%% Kalyanasv change: the above line becomes the following %%%%%
FUNCTION {large.space} { "\IEEElargespace " }
```

Then change your main LaTeX file adding in the preamble

```
\providecommand{\IEEElargespace}{, }
```

(or anything you want in place of the "large space" used by `IEEEtran`, here it's a comma followed by a normal space); finally say

```
\bibliographystyle{myIEEEtran}
```

It's better to use a command instead of a hardwired value, so that you can change your mind more easily: you just change the meaning of `\IEEElargespace` in your document.

Comment: If you're not comfortable with editing IEEE's bst file directly, another option would be to edit the .bbl file that is created.